# How does ASP.net handle URL paths that have no routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm new to ASP.NET, but not MVC. I'm curious - how does IIS/ASP.NET handle routes that are not  registered with an ASP.net application?

```
e.g. http://localhost/unregisteredroute
```

If the route is not available in ASP.NET, does IIS take over and look for (`index/default.htm/whatever`)?

Is there some way in ASP.net to specify that all unregistered routes be given 404s, instead of letting IIS resolve the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route you gave as example will probably return a 404 error, because ASP.NET MVC will try to match it against the default route. It will look for a controller called "unregisteredroute" with a method "Index".

May I suggest you read an easy to grasp overview of ASP.NET MVC routing?
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

It's not as flexible as something like NodeJS routes, but it's pretty easy to configure and play with.

Welcome to ASP.NET ;)

Comment: That's what's puzzling me though. ASP.NET looks for a folder named /unregistered route and serves the content inside. The reason I want to know this, is because I have a static folder that I need accessible in my ASP.NET MVC app. I thought I need something along the lines of 'IgnoreRoute', but clearly I don't, because IIS is serving the directory anyway. Any thoughts?

Comment: It depends if you're referring to ASP.NET site, which is file-oriented, or ASP.NET MVC site, which is route/controller oriented. For MVC, usually your static content will be located at /Content folder, which is automatically served as static. ;)

Comment: Can't mark this as the correct answer because ASP.NET is serving static folders without any ignoreRoute parameters, as opposed to throwing 404 responses (which I believe should be the expected behavior)

Comment: Check your Route configuration in App_Start to see if you're missing something! Without more code it's impossible to find out why ;)